# Facebook Login - HWIOAuthBundle - Symfony3

Tags: php, facebook, symfony, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have used this configs for FOSUBUserProvider.php:

```
namespace myapp\UserBundle\Security\Core\User;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\Response\UserResponseInterface;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider as BaseClass;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
class FOSUBUserProvider extends BaseClass
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function connect(UserInterface $user, UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $property = $this->getProperty($response);
        $username = $response->getUsername();
        //on connect - get the access token and the user ID
        $service = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();
        $setter = 'set'.ucfirst($service);
        $setter_id = $setter.'Id';
        $setter_token = $setter.'AccessToken';
        //we "disconnect" previously connected users
        if (null !== $previousUser = $this->userManager->findUserBy(array($property => $username))) {
            $previousUser->$setter_id(null);
            $previousUser->$setter_token(null);
            $this->userManager->updateUser($previousUser);
        }
        //we connect current user
        $user->$setter_id($username);
        $user->$setter_token($response->getAccessToken());
        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $username = $response->getUsername();
        $user = $this->userManager->findUserBy(array($this->getProperty($response) => $username));
        //when the user is registrating
        if (null === $user) {
            $service = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();
            $setter = 'set'.ucfirst($service);
            $setter_id = $setter.'Id';
            $setter_token = $setter.'AccessToken';
            // create new user here
            $user = $this->userManager->createUser();
            $user->$setter_id($username);
            $user->$setter_token($response->getAccessToken());
            //I have set all requested data with the user's username
            //modify here with relevant data
            $user->setUsername($username);
            $user->setEmail($username);
            $user->setPassword($username);
            $user->setEnabled(true);
            $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
            return $user;
        }
        //if user exists - go with the HWIOAuth way
        $user = parent::loadUserByOAuthUserResponse($response);
        $serviceName = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();
        $setter = 'set' . ucfirst($serviceName) . 'AccessToken';
        //update access token
        $user->$setter($response->getAccessToken());
        return $user;
    }
}
```

The problem that i've got is the following:

1. If i login with facebook, and i already have an account registered with the same e-mail, i want to take the response->email from facebook, and just update the facebook_id column.
2. I don't want to insert another row if an account with the same email exists.

Does someone knows what should i update to my code?
Thank you.

Comment: You would need to get the email from the response object, and then get the user by email.

Comment: Worth noting however, that's pretty insecure.  Your best bet would be to return an error letting the user know they already have an account registered and give them the ability inside your app firewall to connect a facebook account.

eg.  I registered with an email and password.  Later I login and decide I want to be able to auth with my facebook account, so I login then 'connect' my facebook account.  You would then simply store the auth token, set the username to whatever facebook returns for the username and you're all set.

Comment: @Sean That's what i really want to make, but i dont know how.

Comment: Beyond the scope to write all the code for you, but I'll give you a pseudo outline of what you should do.

Comment: @Sean can we continue the conversation into a chat?

Comment: sorry man, but I've actually got to get back to work but the answer below should give you a reasonably good starting point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Leave your authentication code as it is, no need to really change anything there.
2. I assume you've got some sort of ability for a user to 'manage' their profile, so simply add a button we will label it 'connect facebook' for arguments sake.
3. Make sure you've got your facebook auth code setup and handle the return with a post back;

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#facebook-button').click(function() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
               // Your auth response frmo faceook will contain an email, username, profile photo, etc
               // console.log(response) to see exactly what's being returned
              
               $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: {{ path('user_profile_update_post_path') }},
                  data: [username: response.username, facebookId: response.facebookToken, /* etc */],
                  success: successCallback,
                  dataType: 'json'
                });
            }
        }, {scope: 'email'});
    });
});
```

By storing the facebook username and token etc, users should then be able to auth with both email/password and/or facebook

Comment: U didn't got it :( My facebook login is working. If i don't have any account in my database, it will send me to register, and everything will work fine: normal login + facebook login. BUT if i register normal (no facebook), and i try after to login via facebook, it won't work, because i don't have stored that facebook_id in my DB

Comment: I get that, I don't think you're understanding my solution above.

Comment: Look at the code, this is for a user who is ALREADY logged in with the normal login.  They're 'authenticating' with facebook with that code, facebook is then sending a response object back to you.  You then take that response object, and update the users account on your end with the facebook_id, etc.

Comment: Then next time the user logs in they should be able to authenticate with facebook just fine.

Comment: The code above is not redirecting you to the hwioauth system :)  It's simply updating the users profile